# Inject a React component into HTML

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to receive a piece of HTML markup from an external source and inject React components into specific parts of it before it gets rendered.

To achieve this I have been playing around with *react-html-parser* (https://github.com/wrakky/react-html-parser)

I had this example working... although, it feels hacky and cannot possibly the best way to achieve this.

```
// a simple component
const Image = props => {
    return <img {...props}/>    
};

// this resource comes from an external source and can differ
// ultimately, I would like to be able to target certain elements selecting their data-attributes
// to insert a React component
const externalHTML = '<div class="image"></div>';

// using the react-html-parser library to convert the externalHTML into a React component
const DynamicReactComponent = ReactHtmlParser(externalHTML);

// manually injecting a React component into the dynamically created component
DynamicReactComponent.props.children.push(<Image src="something/anything.jpg" />);
```

Another example, with a bit more complicated setup;

```
const externalHTML = '
    <div class="someClass">
        <figure class="image">
            <img src=""/>
            <figcaption></figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>';

// using the react-html-parser library to convert the externalHTML into a React component
const DynamicReactComponent = ReactHtmlParser(externalHTML);

// way too hacky....
// and it does not fully work
DynamicReactComponent.props.children.map(child => {
    if(typeof child === 'object' && 'type' in child) {
        switch(child.type) {

            case 'img':
                // this cannot be done as it's readonly
                child.props.src = 'something/anything.jpg';
                break;

            case 'figcaption':
                return child.props.children.push(<Text/>)

            default:
        }
    }
});
```

In this example I wish to add a src to the image element and a caption to the figcaption.
The rest of the mark up needs to stay untouched, but should be rendered accordingly.
Just to clarify, I *have*   prepared logic to *Reactify* attributes, e.g. `class` becomes `className`.

I know that *react-html-parser* has a custom way to transform nodes. But this forces me to define in code what the outcome should look like. The HTML I receive from the external source is dynamic and the amount of e.g. `div` elements (and their attributes) wrapping an `image` may vary.

I feel a bit lost. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I can think of one other way and it may feel hacky as well. but i will still give it a go.

Since, it is standard HTML file, i think you can somehow add it as a new file.. and import it in index.html in public folder using link : <link href="extern.html" rel="import" /> synchronously. Then change its props using React or vanilla javascript should be alright i think. I will chime in more if think of any other way around.

Comment: What is the larger goal here? Are you working on a CMS like system? Other than that, the HTML templates are not communicating clearly where the insertion sites are. Unless this is explicit in the markup, it's will be challenging to design a solution which is low maintenance.

Comment: Yes, that is right. The larger goal here is a CMS like system.

Comment: CMS html templates are not vanilla html. They use pseudo attributes or tags to denote content sites. Take a look at https://github.com/wix/react-templates, hope this helps.

Comment: @hazardous, sorry I did not respond earlier. Of course, I can specify the insertion sites with e.g. data attributes :) that is totally fine.

Comment: Go with an existing solution like react templates.

Comment: I think dynamic module will be handy, treat your HTML like javascript, but not assign to the variable , but building dynamic component. So the outlet will be adjusted to parent and new incoming HTML structure to.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `ReactDOMServer` to inject React elements into HTML markup (`ReactDOMServer.renderToString` is available in browser too). The step by step algorithm will be:

1) render your React element as a string

2) create a `template` element and paste loaded HTML into it's `innerHTML` property (you need `template` since you want to inject React *before* HTML will be rendered)

3) inject HTML of React component into specific element inside `template`

4) render `template` content on the page

5) hydrate React component if needed

Check this demo on StackBlitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yvncqj

Answer (score 0):

I strongly belive it can be done in Gatsby.

Similiar plugin example: [gatsby-remark-custom-image-component](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-remark-custom-image-component/?=html)

As you can see in description - image node is transformed into react component.

[Custom components](https://using-remark.gatsbyjs.org/custom-components/#mapping-from-generic-html-elements) can be used - markdown exmaple but shows `htmlAst` usage - dig into this (AST manipulations)

[YAML 2 HTML](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-yaml-full-markdown/?=html#gatsby-yaml-full-markdown) shows simple example for more structured data.

Gatsby can handle data from any imaginable data source.